# Hamiltonian of general three body problem

Tags: solar-system, stellar-dynamics

i try to extend my analysis from planar restricted three body problem to the general one.

Is there anyone that can help me to find out the Hamiltonian for this prolem in cartesian coordinates?

I need the hamiltonian of 3D case somethink like eq.(1) in this [article](http://iopscience.iop.org/1538-3881/145/3/63/pdf/1538-3881_145_3_63.pdf) or in this one [paper](http://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2009/02/aa10843-08.pdf) again eq.1 . Because my symplectic integrator can be used only if I have the fixed cartesian coordinates.

Thanks

Comment: This should probably be migrated over to Physics

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include more information on what exactly you have problems with? The way you currently specified it, it's too broad and rather unclear what exactly it even pertains to (tags you used help a bit, but not too much). If I get you correctly, you're after Hamiltonian form of the three-body problem? If that's the case then you might find [this article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Three_body_problem) useful.

Comment: Yes, something like that but, in the wiki example the Hamiltonian is for the planar case. I need the hamiltonian of 3D case somethink like eq.(1) in this article [link](http://iopscience.iop.org/1538-3881/145/3/63/pdf/1538-3881_145_3_63.pdf) or in this one [link](http://www.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2009/02/aa10843-08.pdf) again eq.1

Answer (score 3):

The condition $$\sum_{i=1}^{3}m_iq_i'=0$$
of [this paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/1538-3881/145/3/63/pdf/1538-3881_145_3_63.pdf) generalizes to
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}m_iq_i'=0,$$
meaning the [barycenter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy) should be at the origin of the frame.

Equation (1) generalizes to
$$H=\frac{1}{2}\sum\frac{|p_i'|^2}{m_i}-\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1, j\neq i}^n\frac{m_im_j}{|q_i'-q_j'|}.$$
The first part is the total [kinetic energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy) of the system relative to the barycenter, written in terms of [momenta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Momentum): $$E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2=\frac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{p}{m}\right)^2=\frac{1}{2}\frac{p^2}{m}.$$
The second part is the sum of all [self-potential energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy) between each pair of (spherical) objects, with Newton's gravitational constant $G$ set to 1.

See also [n-body problem on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-body_problem).

The 3-dimensional 3-body (or n-body) problem is like the planar version. Just take 3-dimensional vectors for $p_i'$ and $q_i'$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe move your planar restricted problem to a 3D orbital restricted one.
(i.e. first two bodies in fixed orbit then solve for third body off the plane)